# Ruby Interpreter(CUI) 2.2.4p230 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash

My command prompt keeps bringing up Ruby *Interpreter(CUI) 2.2.4p230 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working* this message when I try to access all my ruby projects. I'm currently using ruby version 2.2.4, rails version 5.0.0 and windows version 10 (recently updated to windows 10 from 8.1). On my git bash every thing seems to work fine,I don't know what went wrong to my command prompt.

**Relevant Things :**
I used railsinstaller to install my ruby, recently updated to windows 10 and recently tried to install **ANSICON** but it failed somehow.

Comment: try removing and reinstalling it

Comment: I did that but it didn't help

Comment: @maxpleaner Yap I did that do , but its not helping